# Can I add a compound index that includes the table's primary key when using Core Data with a SQLite backing store?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, query-optimization

I am working on an iOS 7 app that is using Core Data persisted with a SQLite store. I am trying to optimize for reading.

I've been following the advice in [this blog post](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/01/optimizing-core-data-searches-and-sorts/), which suggests using compound indices that will include columns used in both the where clause and the order by clause of slow queries. However, one of my queries is selecting with a where clause based on the Core Data managed primary key being in a subquery:

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, ... FROM ZMODEL t0 
WHERE t0.Z_PK IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  
ORDER BY t0.ZTITLE LIMIT 99999
```

I can't get SQLite to explain the query for me exactly since `_Z_intarray0` is a temporary table (or is it?), but I can substitute some values in to (potentially) get some guidance from the database:

```
explain query plan SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, ... FROM ZMODEL t0 
                   WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN (1,2,3)  
                   ORDER BY t0.ZTITLE LIMIT 99999;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE ZMODEL AS t0 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~3 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

I would think that at the database level I could add an index on the primary key and the title column in order to not generate a temporary index for the order by clause; however, Core Data is managing the primary key and I cannot add a multicolumn index with it since it is not an object-level attribute.

Is there a way to speed up this query with an index or another solution?